# How to place a string value by DESC in order by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I write a procedure in mySQL,

```
IN `para`  varchar(4)
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...

if (para = 'asc') THEN

SELECT officeCode, city, country
from offices
ORDER BY country ;

ELSE

SELECT officeCode, city, country
from offices
ORDER BY country DESC;


END if;
END
```

That code is ok, but I wonder are there any other way to make shorter, like this (para is parameter when call procedure):

```
BEGIN
SELECT officeCode, city, country
from offices
ORDER BY country *para* ;

END
--------but this is not work-------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily dynamically generate the query's text based on `para` using any scripting language of your choice, if that works in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick you can use with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT officeCode,
       city,
       country
FROM offices
ORDER BY CASE WHEN para = 'asc'  THEN Country ELSE '1' END ASC,
         CASE WHEN para != 'asc' THEN Country ELSE '1' END DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.  One is to fiddle with the `order by`:

```
SELECT officeCode, city, country
FROM offices
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN para = 'asc' THEN country END),
         country DESC;  -- you could use a `case` here but it is not necessary
```

Alternatively, you can use a prepared statement:

```
set @sql = '
SELECT officeCode, city, country
FROM offices
ORDER BY para [dir]';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[dir]', (case when para = 'asc' then 'asc' else 'desc' end));

prepare q from @sql;
execute q;
```

The advantage of dynamic SQL is that you have a hope that the query will use an index.